# MT deployment is stuck on deploying for four days

Tags: microsoft-translator

I trained a new English to French MT. Training went ok with a 62+ BLEU score, but deployment is stuck. Any idea what's going on?  I've been able to train and deploy in the past.  This is the first time since the move to Azure.  Anything new I need to know?

This is the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGQYG.jpg) I get.  It's been pending since 07/13.

Here is more [details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S73p8.jpg).

When I click on Request Deployment, I get this message:

Your request to deploy this system was submitted on 13-Jul-2017 by XXXX.

Deployment will take up to 2 business days. Project owners will be notified when the system is deployed.

Comment: You need to provide more info

Comment: What did you do to start the deployment? Are there any logs that have been generated?

Comment: Added more info.  I am not aware of a place to get a log in the Translator Hub.

Comment: Reading https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1128370-hub-deployment-of-a-custom-system-requires-a-micr, it looks like deployment might be failing because of a bad connection to my Azure account, but I have that connection and it's showing in the hub, right : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAStf.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Deployments failed for all customers since Thursday July 13. Expected to resume fully on Tuesday July 18.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisWendt!

Comment: While I have you Chris, I just wanted a confirmation that redoing a training should give me a custom MT based on your new Neural MT model/engine?  This is the main reason I'm retraining our engine.  Am I correct?

Comment: Hub customized systems are based on treelet, phrasal or hiero decoders, depending on the language pair. That has an advantage in adhering to the terminology used in your training documents, a disadvantage in terms of fluency.

Comment: So in other words, if I train the engine, I don't get the neural MT.  If I want the neural MT, I need to use the generalnn category in the API call.  Now, I just need to figure out how to do that in the SDL Trados Studio plugin.  I'm guessing they are not supporting it, but I sent them a support ticket about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing NMT is now available using [Custom Translator (Preview)](http://www.aka.ms/CustomTranslator). The new Translator Text API v3 works with Custom Translator, and the supported languages are limited to pairs where [NMT languages](http://aka.ms/TranslatorLanguages) exist.

Thank you.